# like/love + to infinitive for habits and choices - shades in meaning

Tags: gerunds, british-english, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I have come across the following sentence (no context, the rubric of the task is to fill in the gaps with the words in capital letters, making all the necessary changes) in Macmillan Exam Skills for Russia by Malcolm Mann and Steve Taylore-Knowles, 2007:

> My grandad loves to .... and we often go out on his boat. **SAIL**

If not for the particle 'to' before the ellipsis, my choice would be 'sailing' because according to Michael Swan in his *Practical English Usage* (Fully Revised) Third Edition OUP, 2005

> to talk about enjoying activities in general, we can use ‘like… ing’ (especially in British English)'.

Why would authors give so little context and provide our students with such an ambiguous example?

Furthermore, the part of the rule that one 'can use ‘like + infinitive’ to talk about choices and habits' hasn't been covered/discussed anywhere in the coursebook.

What would your choice be if not for the particle 'to'? I'm mostly interested in British English native speakers' answers.

Comment: If the book hasnt covered 'like ...ing' then you wouldnt expect it to be used in an exercise. As a Brit i think i would prefer 'like ...ing' over 'like to ...', but there's not much in it, they have identical meanings.

Comment: It's more important that you get an accurate answer about British English than it be written by a native speaker.

Comment: I need an accurate answer from a native speaker, yes.. @snailboat

Comment: No, just an accurate answer.  It doesn't matter who writes it.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/whats-the-difference-between-i-love-singing-and-i-love-to-sing

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not a Brit but still... my two cents that might be helpful.

*like, love* etc are special verbs that take both, the gerund and to-infinitive.

> I love reading and **also** I love to read

Likewise,

> I like reading and **also** I like to read

Note that when hate, like, love and prefer are used with would or should, only the ***to-infinitive*** is used, not the ***-ing*** form. The reference is [Cambridge Dictionary.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing) Another reference is [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17259/why-is-enjoy-to-verb-incorrect) and a forum discussion is [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=708002).

These are called as *verb patterns* and there's no way you can come out with rules. You just need to remember, they way I do! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following solution because the instructions: "to make all the necessary changes" must also include modifying the given word SAIL. Otherwise, merely adding the verb **sail** in the gap seems a bit too trivial, don't you think?

> My grandad loves to **go sailing** and we often go out on his boat.

With sports or outdoor activities (not games) the following structure can be used:
Like/Love + To Go + Verb + ING

There is no significant difference in meaning between *I like camping*, and *I like to go camping*

- I like (to go) camping
- You love (to go) skating
- She likes (to go) swimming
- We love (to go) running
- They like rock climbing

In the negative form, the *to go* can be omitted.

- I/You/We/They dislike camping
- I/You/We/They don't like camping
- I/You/We/They don't like **to go camping**
- She / He dislikes swimming
- She / He doesn't like swimming
- She / He doesn't like **to go swimming**

Sources: [English Vocabulary](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/english-vocabulary-gerunds-used-for-sports/): *Gerunds Used for Sports*; [Guide](http://www.businessenglishresources.com/31-2/student-section/student-handouts/infinitive-vs-gerund-combining-two-verbs/): *Using Two Verbs Together*; [Fifty Ways to Practice Grammar](https://books.google.it/books?id=poQlDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=%22like%20to%20go%22%20ing%20grammar&source=bl&ots=-oEFnAucfm&sig=LCAVLjrZ-cjrSz37gEMdKxXEzlk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwmofq87_QAhWk34MKHesrC-I4ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=%22like%20to%20go%22%20ing%20grammar&f=false): *Tips for ESL/EFL Students*

Comment: your comment about the negative form of 'like/love to go + verb +ING' is a very useful one, I have never come across it, I mean the fact that you can actually omit 'to go'.