# I always get confused between be and being can anyone solve my problem

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, present-participles

1. I don't want you to be here again.
2. I don't want you being here again.

'Being' is always a problem for me. I can use all gerunds but not this one. Please help.

Comment: I don't get this. Are you saying you *don't* have a problem with, for example *I don't want him **coming** here* and *I don't want him **to come** here*?

Comment: What's the difference between 'don't want him coming here' and 'I don't want him to come here'

Comment: I’ve added [tag:infinitive-vs-gerund] to your question. Clicking on that tag and reading some of the questions and answers might be helpful to you, especially [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/53356/9161) This is a pretty common area of confusion.