Is it "try to" or "try+V-ing"?
What should I say here?

Don't try to climb this tree. It's too tall.
Don't try climbing this tree. It's too tall.

How can I differentiate between the two forms in a simple way? I know the rule but I get confused when I want to answer any question, I can't decide what to choose.
Is the answer of this question 'to climb'?
Am I right?

This question is similar to: try+gerund/infinitive (Difference in meaning). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Scroll to the bottom until you reach "try + gerund" https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_or_infinitive_different_list.htm

I know the difference but when I want to answer questions, I get confused and can't decide what to choose.Can anyone tell me a simple way to know which one should I choose?

You have to explain IN the question (not in a comment) why the answer in the older question does not help you. Also, you should have said that you understood the difference, and shared some of the research IN the question. More information and detail you provide, the better it is.

I didn't know that, I'll edit it.

I sympathise with your dilemma, but you still didn't explain why the accepted answer in the older question didn't help you. Here's a similar question of mine posted on EL&U. Note the amount of information and clarification I provided, it's quite detailed. I'm trying to explain why the two constructions confuse me: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117345/how-to-remember-the-difference-between-can-you-try-to-open-and-can-you-try-o

I read it all but I'm a beginner and want some explanation in simple words. And I want someone to tell me if my answer is correct or not with simple explanation.

To try to climb a tree is to attempt to get up into the branches. This is probably what you are warning someone not to do. To try climbing a tree could mean to climb to see what the experience is like, or whether you can solve a problem by doing so. You are right in thinking that (1) is the better choice.

See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226546/difference-between-try-to-do-and-try-doing?rq=1

In the exact context here, it makes no difference whether you use the infinitive or the participle. But there can be a difference between #1 "Have you tried to open the door?" and #2 "Have you tried opening the door?". #1 can only be speaker asking whether addressee has attempted to open the door. #2 can have that meaning as well, but it can also be used to ask whether opening the door (which assumes addressee can easily do if he wants) resolves some problem (for example, responding to someone saying "It's too hot to work in my garden shed").

Thank you all.I really apreciate your answer,Kate. It's simple and clear.


How can I differentiate between the two forms in a simple way?

There are no rules in English - there is guidance.
Some guidance is too complicated to follow and individual exceptions have to be learned.
In this construction the semantic difference that the "to infinitive" indicates a complete action from starting to finishing and including both the start and the finish of the action.
The "ing-form" (participle, gerund, adjective, verbal noun) always refers to (i) a duration that starts 0.001 seconds after the action starts, and ends 0.001 seconds before the action ends or (ii) times when the action, within that time, is taking place. The "ing-form" is therefore an expression of [continuous] action taking place, but it is always action that is technically unfinished at the time referred to.
The "ing-form" describes the process of the verb.
The "to infinitive" describes an incidence of the verb.
Don't try to climb - "to climb" is equivalent of "Don't try the ascension"
Don't try climbing - "climbing" is equivalent of "Don't try the action of climbing" (as I mentioned, that "climbing" has started but not finished.")
You must bear in mind that both
Don't try to climb this tree. It's too tall.
and
Don't try climbing this tree. It's too tall.
are valid. It does not matter which you use because the purpose of the sentence is not "climbing" but is safety advice, and both sentences express this.

Thanks for your answer.
