# I was thinking or I thought

Tags: idiomatic-language

> I **[was thinking/thought]**, if you were interested, you could come over to dinner Saturday.

Does using "I was thinking" sound as a more spontaneous invite/idea than using "I thought"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "I love singing" and "I love to sing"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/whats-the-difference-between-i-love-singing-and-i-love-to-sing)

Comment: The tense is different, but the distinction in verb form is the same.

Comment: @JasonBassford ?? These aren't at all comparable.

Comment: @userr2684291 My second comment was in reference to my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think that technically both are correct. However, "I was thinking" sounds more appropriate in my opinion as it's softer. Plus, it seems to me that it's more often used by natives in this kind of context which is about a suggestion of doing something.